# C# Unassigned local variable?

Tags: c#, windows, console, console-application

How do I fix the error: "unassigned local variable" for grade? I tried using public and private prefixes before 'string', but it didn't work. Could someone please explain what private and public does as well?
Thanks.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool answered = false;
        string grade;

        while(answered == false)
        {
            Console.Write("What is your mark? ");
            int mark = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            answered = true;        

            if(mark >= 90 && mark <= 100)
            {
                grade = "A";

            } else if(mark >= 80 && mark < 90)
            {
                grade = "B";

            } else if(mark >= 55 && mark < 80)
            {
                grade = "C";

            } else if(mark >= 40 && mark < 55)
            {
                grade = "D";

            } else if(mark >= 0 && mark < 40)
            {
                grade = "E";

            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your mark between 0-100");
                answered = false;
            }
                Console.WriteLine("Your grade is a " + grade);
                Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does `grade` get assigned if it hits the `else` block?

Comment: Assign it something, like an empty string?

Comment: Assigning it an empty string worked! Thanks.

Comment: Don't get ahead of yourself, though. Sure, the error goes away, but now the output will be incomplete. You need to test that `grade` isn't empty before writing the output to the console. Or maybe there's a different requirement.

Comment: The program now fully works. I added another if statement at the end, because I ended up running into another problem where the message get's printed all the time.
I tried using try and catch statements to avoid errors and crashes if the user enters a string instead of an integer, but the message in the catch statement get's printed 100% of the time for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you assign a value to `grade` in all case, so that it always has a value. You can start by just initializing it with a value:

```
string grade = "";
```

Alternatively, set it to a value in all your conditions, which means setting it in your else here:

```
 else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your mark between 0-100");   
    grade = "";
 }
```

Comment: Why did I have to assign it a value though? Not assigning seems to work with numbers. Is it just something I have to do with strings?

Comment: The difference is not the data type; it's the scope. Fields that aren't initialized will have their default values (e.g. 0, null). Local variables have to be initialized before they're used.

Comment: To enhance discussion I read "String.empty" don't create object, when "" make it. 

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905378/string-empty-versus

Comment: @Vonkel. it's true, but for the purpose of explaining the problem here, the difference isn't a big deal.