# What's the different between ldsfld and ldstr in IL?

Tags: .net, cil

I've read some article about String.Empty vs "" and I also do test by my self. Different between them are below.

String.Empty

```
L_0001: ldsfld string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
```

""

```
L_0001: ldstr ""
```

After I talk with my friends they argue that String.Empty is faster than "" because under the hood (at assembly level) ldstr do more 1 circle than ldsfld. (I can't remember steps that make them different)

I want to know how can I check about this aspect of performance.

Comment: Have you ever tried to measure this in code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between String.Empty and ""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and)

Comment: @Yves I've tried to do about 1,000,000 loop but performance output is vary, sometime "" faster sometime string.Empty.

Comment: @Darin: I think this is different question because I talk at lower level than IL (may be internal memory mangement).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ldsfld` operation pushes the value of a static field onto the evaluation stack, while the `ldstr` pushes a reference to a meta data string literal.

The performance difference (if any) would be minimal. Newer versions of the compiler actually substitutes `""` for `String.Empty`.

You should also consider the readability and maintainability of the code. Using `String.Empty` it's clearer that you actually mean an empty string and not just forgot to type something in the string literal.

#### Edit:

I took a look at the native code created.

C# 3, release mode, x86:

```
        string a = String.Empty;
0000002a  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[0356102Ch]
0000002f  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax
        string b = "";
00000032  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[0356202Ch]
00000038  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax
```

C# 3, release mode, x64:

```
        string a = String.Empty;
0000003b  mov         rax,12711050h 
00000045  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax] 
00000048  mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax 
        string b = "";
0000004d  mov         rax,12713048h 
00000057  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax] 
0000005a  mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rax
```

So, in the end the code is identical.

Comment: +1 for looking at assembly, because this is what actually makes the difference.

Comment: What is your method of looking at the assembly?

Answer (score 7):

`ldstr` is IL to load a specific string token from metadata.

`ldsfld` is IL to load the specified *field* - which in this case is `string.Empty`.

In other words, they're entirely different operations, which happen to have the same result in this case. How are they implemented at the assembly level? Well, that could very well depend on the version of the CLR you're using. Ask your friends which version they're talking about... desktop (32 or 64 bit? 1, 2, 2SP1, 2SP2, 4?), Compact Framework (again, which version?), Silverlight (which operating system, which version?) Did they use `cordbg` on the code you're actually discussing, or did they do it on some sample code, which may not have been optimized in the same way?

I would (and have) argued that you should use whichever you find more readable. Personally I prefer `""` but others prefer `string.Empty`. That's fine. Arguing for one over the other on performance reasons requires *evidence* though... and ideally, evidence based on the code you're actually writing, not a micro-benchmark.

I would be *astonished* to see code where any difference between the two actually led to a significant performance difference in real code - other than in situations where there's probably a better way of approaching the task anyway.

Answer (score 7):

From .NET 4.5 the difference ***in this case*** is: exactly nothing. It looks like the JIT now detects this ldsfld and injects the interned empty string directly.

You can tell this because in < 4.5, you can change the value of string.Empty via reflection and it impacts code using string.Empty. Nasty but possible. From 4.5 this no longer works. If you can check via reflection you get the hacked version, but code using string.Empty via ldsfld gets the correct empty string rather than the hacked version.