# .NET Reflection: MissingFieldException with some fields

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm making a .NET-compatible compiler and today I have come across a very strange bug. I'm testing field getters and sometimes I get `MissingFieldException` with some of the built-in types' fields.

The fields I'm troubled with are:

- `MaxValue` of all numerics
- `MinValue` of all numerics
- `double.PositiveInfinity`
- `double.NegativeInfinity`
- `double.NaN`

The code compiles fine: during compilation, the `FieldInfo` is found and a corresponding `ldsfld` is emitted. During the run phase, however, the aforementioned exception is being thrown. And this happens **only for some fields**: `Type.EmptyTypes` compiles and works just as expected!

I tried to investigate the IL-code which `csc` emits for those fields, but it does some optimizations and the program just pushes the actual value to the stack instead of calling the field. While this is, apparently, a more efficient way, for now I would like to keep my compiler as simple as possible.

Has anyone came across similar issues?

Comment: It would really help if you could give a single specific but complete example.

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: The compiler is quite huge and most of its code is irrelevant to the subject. The emit code is as simple as this: `gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, fieldInfo);`. Debugging shows that during compile time the `fieldInfo` value contains the valid `FieldInfo` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to investigate the IL-code which `csc` emits for those fields,
>   but it does some optimizations and the program just pushes the actual
>   value to the stack instead of calling the field.

All the fields in your list are ***constant*** fields. Therefore their values will be copied into the IL generated from code referencing them.

Comment: But the field does exist. I tried the following code:
    `var pty = typeof(int).GetField("MaxValue");`
    `var result = pty.GetValue(null);`
and it gave the result.

Comment: I agree the field does exist. I'm not sure I understand exactly how you arrive at your `MissingFieldException`. You say you're testing "field getters". What are those? I can only say that if you write code which "reads" `int.MaxValue` directly, like `int myInt = int.MaxValue;`, then the IL will not contain a read of the field. The field is constant (`.IsLiteral` returns `true`). The value will be hard-coded into the IL instead. On the other hand, `var e = Type.EmptyTypes;` will compile into IL that actually reads the run-time value of `EmptyTypes`. `EmptyTypes` is not constant (literal).

Comment: So you're saying that if a field has the flag `IsLiteral` raised, its value cannot be retrieved via `ldsfld` and **must** be hard-coded into the IL?

Comment: I decided to stick with that method after all. Seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. I'm no expert in IL, I just know that the C# compiler translates uses of constant fields into "hard-coded" values in the IL. It looks like the thread [What's the different between `ldsfld` and `ldstr` in IL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674288/) is related. Note that [`string.Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty) is ***not*** marked constant/literal, whereas using the (compile-time constant) string literal `""` in the C# source code is equivalent to using a constant/literal field with the value `""`.

Comment: It seems that literal fields can only be of primitive numeric types. Therefore `DateTime.MaxValue` is not a literal field either.

Comment: @Impworks In C# the following rules exist: "The _type_ specified in a constant declaration must be `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `bool`, `string`, an _enum-type_, or a _reference-type_." (from the C# Language Specification, §10.4 Constants). Furthermore "the only possible value for constants of _reference-types_ other than `string` is `null`". So those are the C# rules. I guess the .NET rules are similar (they have to allow at least the same constants, of course).