# How to default null session values to blank strings in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I'm used to using VB.net for web programming.

Often, I have something like:

```
Dim s as string = Session("s")
```

I get a string value for `s` from the web session.  If there is no value in the web session, I get a blank string.

However, AFAIK, in C#, I have to have something like the code below to do the same thing.

```
string s;
try { s = Session["s"].ToString(); }
catch { s = ""; }
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: In VB, you get Nothing if you attempt to retrieve a session variable that does not exist.  Most of my session retrieval code looks like:  Dim s As String = Session("S")  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then DoSomethingWithS(s) End If

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a quick way of doing this:

```
s = (string)Session["s"] ?? "";
```

This will cast **Session["s"]** to a string, and if it is not null, return the value. If it is null, it will return an empty string. The "`a ?? b`" expression is essentially the same as "`a != null ? a:b`" (**??** is compiled more efficiently though)

Something else to keep in mind: you should never use exceptions for normal application logic.

Comment: Short, sweet.  No additional functions.  I like it.

Comment: The following syntax may be cleaner: String Test = (Session["Test"] ?? String.Empty).ToString();

Comment: It's not cleaner, but it is safer if Session["Test"] is not a string (which I believe is not the case here)

Comment: As a side note, I tend to use String.Empty instead of "".  Seems more readable.

Comment: There's no longer any benefit in that. "" is just as efficient as String.Empty. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and

Comment: @Chris: That's generally a .NET coding standard.

Comment: Phil, I'd say that if `Session["Test"]` is not a string, despite our expectations, then it's better to throw on a failed downcast than to return the `ToString` value. In short, I would not recommend Moo's code over yours.

Comment: @Steven: I agree. But it's always best to mention this "restriction" when proposing this solution of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because string is reference type then is nullable, so you can check for empty or null by means of **string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)**:

```
string s = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)strObject) ? string.Empty : strObject.ToString();
```

Otherwise (as *Philippe Leybaert* says) you can use ?? operator.

Comment: String is a reference type, so it is always nullable. Your code doesn't even compile because `string?` is not valid syntax.

Comment: You are right Philippe, string is a reference type. I have changed my code to reflect such idea.

Answer (score -3):

I almost agree to Philippe, but it only works if "s" is present in the session, otherwise there will be a KeyNotFoundException. This code checks it, but does not solve the NULL issue of Philippe.

```
s= Session.ContainsKey("s")?Session["s"]:"";
```

So to cover both possibilities, it becomes mre complex:

```
s = Session.ContainsKey("s")?(Session["s"]??""):"";
```

It does not really make it easier, but the performance should be better than catching an exception.

Comment: I don't believe that it throws any such exception. The documentation (at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0yd7k72.aspx) reads: "The value in the collection with the specified name. If the specified key is not found, attempting to get it returns null, and attempting to set it creates a new element using the specified key."

Comment: Indeed, Session will return null if the key is not found. It will not throw an exception

Comment: Yup - in the original question, it is the .ToString() call that is throwing the exception.