# Why to use name = System.String.Empty; instead of name = "";

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between String.Empty and “”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and)

Which one is better?

```
name = System.String.Empty;
```

OR

```
name = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it because FxCop complains if I don't.  More readable?, hardly.

Answer (score 0):

I use "" as it's considerably easier on the eye than `String.Empty`.  It hasn't caused me any problems as of yet, and I've been developing in .Net for years.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** This is only true till .NET 1.1. as per [What is the difference between String.Empty and "" (empty string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and/151527#151527) not true for later versions.

If you say `""` you are creating a new `object`, where as [`String.Empty` is a read-only field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx) already initialized, it creates no object.

Comment: Not true as per answers in duplicate question