# Benefits of using string.Empty

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between String.Empty and “”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and)

Why it is recommended to use `string.Empty` instead of `""`? From one side, I understand, that it makes code clearer, without "Magic constants". Is there any another technical benefits of using `string.Empty`?
Thanks.

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Brad Abrams](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx) blog:

> the difference between String.Empty and “” are pretty small, but there
>   is a difference.  “” actually creates an object, it will likely be
>   pulled out of the string intern pool, but still… while String.Empty
>   creates no object… so if you are really looking for ultimately in
>   memory efficiency, I suggest String.Empty.  However, you should keep
>   in mind the difference is so trival you will like never see it in your
>   code…

It's pretty insignificant.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this has been answered before, but to summarize: **preference** and **readability.**

They are completely equivalent, and are up to whatever you and your fellow developers prefer, just be consistent. :)