# What is difference between single and multiple declarations in one line?

Tags: c#

I would like to know the differences between these two ways of declaring variables.

Type 1

```
private string procedure_add = "";
private string procedure_update = "";
private string procedure_delete = "";
```

Type 2

```
private string procedure_add = "", procedure_update = "", procedure_delete = "";
```

Does this give the same effect?. Is the memory consumption the same?

Comment: I would like to suggest you use `string.Empty` instead of `""`.

Comment: this should be explained in various books about programming. You can check out [the list of freely available books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/238902) here on SO

Comment: Thanks all. @Serge string.Empty and "" what is the different?.

Comment: @Serge: I'd suggest the use of whatever you prefer, as long as it's consistent.

Comment: @Sagotharan, here is the answer: [What is the difference between String.Empty and “”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/). Long story short, for readability reason.

Comment: @Serge: Right, I find `""` to be more readable than `String.Empty`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no any difference.   it's all about the accessibility.  the way how the code looks. 
suppose if you have 10000+ line of code, while editing you may get stumped by identifying the "," in declaration .

1. if you have one or two variable, then declare it in a single line
2. writing each declaration in separate line will look code cleaner, and better to debug.

this method which i prefer to use.

```
private string yourVar = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no any difference. Just coding style.

**EDIT**

As @Aphelion mantioned in first case you can modify accessibility. 
From the code generation point of view the both version produce exactly the same `IL`

```
MyClass..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldstr       ""
IL_0006:  stfld       UserQuery+MyClass.procedure_add
IL_000B:  ldarg.0     
IL_000C:  ldstr       ""
IL_0011:  stfld       UserQuery+MyClass.procedure_update
IL_0016:  ldarg.0     
IL_0017:  ldstr       ""
IL_001C:  stfld       UserQuery+MyClass.procedure_delete
IL_0021:  ldarg.0     
IL_0022:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0027:  ret
```

Comment: Exactly. However using single lines you can modify the accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, the one is just a short-hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think no different, from my understanding second type is to minimize the line of code.

Comment: +1 Thanks for immediate answer. Expand your answer, it more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the overall "They are the same, but differ in readability" I would like to add 3 remarks:

1. In Visual Basic 6 (and earlier) `Dim x , y as Integer` would result in y being an Integer and x a Variant
2. In C `int *ip, i;` would result in ip being a pointer to an int and i to be an int.
3. In unsafe C# code `int *ip, i;` will result in ip being a pointer to int and i ALSO being a pointer to int.