# Most elegant way to check to see if a NameValueCollection has value

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

I have a simple line of code: `lead.InternalCompany = nvCollection["ic"];`

I want to set `lead.InternalCompany` to the value retrieved, but if nothing is there to a blank string `""`

I've tried to use `nvCollection["ic"].HasValue();`

I know I could do something simple like this

```
string value = nvCollection["ic"];
if (value == null) // key doesn't exist
    {
        lead.InternalCompany = "";
    }
```

I'd ideally like a ternary `if statement` to accomplish this

Comment: Its better to use `String.NullorEmpty(string)` instead of `value == null`

Comment: @Shaharyar: That would depend on your implementation details. As far as we know, an empty string is a perfectly valid value. (and in Jon Harding's case, it's redundant as he wants to default to empty anyway)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It
>   returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it
>   returns the right operand.

```
lead.InternalCompany = nvCollection["ic"] ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: I would suggest using string.Empty rather than "";

Comment: [There is no difference between `String.Empty` and `""`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and-empty-string).

Comment: `string.Empty` is clearer to read and avoids accidentally typing some random stuff in between the two `"`s

Comment: Regarding `String.Empty` vs `""`: [join the debate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

Comment: const string A_VERY_EMPTY_STRING = "";