# C# OpenFileDialog Empty

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a messagebox if my *picturebox* is empty.

```
if (dial == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    if (openfile.FileName == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Upload Poster");
    }
    else
    {
        this.Close();
        poster = openfile.FileName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand your question

Comment: Me neither, you want a messagebox to show up if user clicks on some button or something while no file uploaded?

Comment: i want to upload picture box image but , if picturebox is empty then open messagebox .

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/677961/How-To-Check-PictureBox-Control-has-image-or-not

Comment: yes it's working thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
{
    Common.MessageBoxUtilities.WarningMessageBox("You Have Image");
}
else if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
{
    Common.MessageBoxUtilities.WarningMessageBox("You Dont Have Image");
}
```

Try something like this?

source: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/677961/How-To-Check-PictureBox-Control-has-image-or-not

Answer (score 0):

try it this way:

```
 if(myPictureBox.Image == NULL)
{
    //MessageBox
}
```

Comment: How will this be a difference? Just asking, not flaming

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and-empty-string
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or

Comment: I've been reviewing your answer, it's an automatic resposne. The question was rather poor, but you've just pasted single `if` statement with no explanation whatsoever.