# Difference between initialize a string to "" or to "".ToString() - Which one should I use?

Tags: c#

How should I initialize an empty string in C# and why? Which one is faster?

```
string myString = "";
```

or

```
string myString = "".ToString();
```

Comment: The second one is pointless. It's already a string

Answer (score 9):

[String.ToString()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2696) just returns the string itself :

```
    public override String ToString() {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        return this;
    }
```

Which means `string myString = "".ToString()` is pointless. After all, it's *already* a string

In fact, given that strings are immutable and, in this case, interned, `""` is the same string instance returned by `String.Empty`

Comment: It also means "".ToString() is likely slightly slower, but to verify one would need to test it.  It's possible it gets optimized by the compiler.

Comment: @Tim what it means, is that the code base is bad with blind copying all around and `ToString()` used to avoid casts

Comment: @Tim The JIT optimizes `"".ToString()` in Release. In all other cases, it is not optimized.

Comment: There are quite a few questions in SO with people blindly using `ToString()` on a field value  column only to *parse* the result back into a date or double.

Answer (score 6):

The second one is redundant. It's already a `string`. So the first one would be the best option.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I've seen the second option in some code made by others and I was wondering which one to use.

Comment: No problem. Like another answer said, string.Empty is another option. They'll perform pretty much identically but some people prefer string.Empty from a code readability standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the first one which is the best option

```
string myString = "";
```

You can also use string.Empty in C#

```
string myString = string.Empty;
```

The second one is pointless because "" which is already a string and converting string("").ToString() is pointless.

Comment: why is the first one the best option? Please explain :)

Comment: One thing is: you cannot use the second one as an optional method parameter. The compiler will say it is not a compile time constant, with first - there is not such error.

Comment: Before .net 2.0 there was a slight difference and "" created a new object where string.Empty did not.  This is no longer true and which one you use comes down to personal preference.  I personally see "" used far more than string.Empty except in really old code.    There are also cases where "" will work but string.Empty causes a compilation error.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and-empty-string  (see the 2 top answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 
    `string.Empty` which is more readable. It has nothing to do with performance.