# Replace is not doing the expected replacement

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a problem in c# with replace in a string with space at the end.

`"ERROR.1️.1.1094".Replace("ERROR.1.", "")`

Expected value is 1.1094 but it's not working.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `Replace` returns a new string, are you not using that value?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("ERROR 1️  1.1094".Replace("ERROR 1 ", "")); doesn't write 1.1094?

Comment: When a method isn't working, please refer to the documentation as the first port of call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0 - The documentation states: _"**Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with another specified Unicode character or String."_

Comment: Actually, even [Intellisense tells you the same thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0mQl.png).

Comment: It's actually a typo. `"ERROR 1️" != "ERROR 1"` both have a single character different. `"1️" != "1"` (Try it in the JS console).

Comment: The duplicate is incorrect, but the question needs to be remained closed (Typo)

Comment: The error is also in this example:

>"ERROR.1️..1.1094".Replace("ERROR.1.", "")

Comment: Gabriel: "but it's not working" is not an adequate problem description. How are we supposed to understand what you expect "working" to be? How do we know what you believe is evidence that it's "not working"? Please edit your question with a [mcve].

Comment: The problem comes from the character used for the digit `one` in the string `"ERROR.1️.1.1094"` It's actually the unicode character [Segmented Digit One](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1FBF1) and **not** the well known *"Digit one"* (ASCII 0x31) which is used in the second part, the string to be searched *"ERROR.1."*

Comment: @Cid That's not the problem. The error persists testing with the string like this:
"ERRORC1️C1.1094".Replace("ERRORC1C", "")

Comment: @Gabriel that's the same thing, the caracter you're using for `1` in `"ERRORC1️C1.1094"` is **different** than the character used in `"ERRORC1C"`. That's like trying to compare `'a'` and `'B'`

Comment: @Cid Okay I understand now. Is there any alternative to use?

Comment: Well, use the same character from both sides

Comment: @Gabriel [check this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SxeoVV)

Comment: Thanks @Cid. God bless you

Comment: @Gabriel God doesn't exist, but thanks anyway

Answer (score -2):

Please try the following
"ERROR 1️  1.1094".Replace("ERROR 1 ", string.Empty)

Comment: How is that different?

Comment: because he is trying to replace a string not a single character, there's a difference they are treated by Replace

Comment: `""` is a string.

Comment: Also, [FYI](https://rextester.com/DUG43981).

Comment: @Llama it is just more memory efficient way to use Replace, "" takes additional space on heap whereas string.Empty doesn't, there is a reason this overload exists in first place.

Comment: 1) Source? 2) How does this help solve OP's problem?

Comment: [Here is a source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151481/3181933) stating the opposite of what you have asserted for all versions of .NET since 2002 (20 years ago).

Comment: In fact if you inspect the IL generated, you can see that `""` and `string.Empty` generate the exact same code (since .net 2.0)

Comment: The very reason to alternative answer was "" not working for @Gabriel in first place :) We all have better things to do , nice chatting to you guyz

Comment: The empty string had nothing to do with the error, it changes nothing to the result. Did you try it? Read my comments under the questions

Comment: But why do you believe that replacing `""` with `string.Empty` will solve OP's problem? Because it won't...